# pst-jtree: How to check whether the current command is issued inside or between a tree

Tags: macros, pstricks, pst-jtree

I would like to define a macro that does something slightly different based on what the most recent non-whitespace character before it is. While I'm hesitant to go into irrelevant details of its use, it's pretty easy to define the kind of behavior I want. For instance:

```
\newcommand{\blah}{%
    \if\prevnonwschar=.
        foo
    \else
        bar
    \fi
 }
```

Then, the following should print `.foo bar`:

```
.\blah\ \blah
```

As should the following (with line breaks, of course):

```
.

\blah\ \blah
```

I would like this to happen even if the period is not printed in the document (in the actual context, it signals the end of an environment).

What would go in place of `\prevnonwschar=.` to let me do this?

Edit: Because of David Carlisle's comment, I'm adding more detail.

The actual use case is defining a shortcut to rescale the branches of a tree in `pst-jtree`. A MWE of a `jtree` looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-jtree}

\begin{document}
\jtree
\! = {X}
    :{Y} {Z}
    :{A} {B}.
\endjtree
\end{document}
```

Note that the `.` is always used to mark the end of the tree (you can use all kinds of `pstricks` commands afterward before `\endjtree` to draw various things).

The code above produces this result:

[image: a simple jtree]

The key `scaleby = x y` can be used to scale the branches of a `jtree`, where `x` and `y` are the scaling factors of the x and y axes. You can set this for all branches in a tree in square brackets after `\jtree`, or you can set this for each branch individually by putting `scaleby = x y` in square brackets prior to the curly braces for each node specified, but it's often useful to set it so that it applies for all subsequent branches of a tree. This can be done as follows:

```
\jtree
\! = {X}
    :{Y} {Z} "{\psset{scaleby = 2 1}}
    :{A} {B}.
\endjtree
```

[image: a jtree with a wider lower level]

In addition, you can use an inline adjunction operator to signal that one tree should be adjoined to a specified point in another. The inline adjunction operator starts with a `!` and is followed by an optional label.

```
\jtree[scaleby = 2 1]
\! = {X}
    :{Y}! {Z}.
\! =<left>[scaleby = 1 1]{A} ^ <right>[scaleby = 1 1]{B}.
\endjtree
```

(`:{A} {B}` is a built-in shortcut for `<left>{A} ^ <right>{B}`, and doesn't handle scaling individual branches consistently, necessitating the more complex expression.)

[image: a jtree with a complex left branch]

Alternatively, you can use `\psset{scaleby = x y}` after the end of the definition of the first tree and before the second tree to set the scaling factor for everything to come (the result is the same as the above picture).

```
\jtree[scaleby = 2 1]
\! = {X}
    :{Y}! {Z}.
\psset{scaleby = 1 1}
\! =:{A} {B}. 
\endjtree
```

Rescaling all the branches to come in a tree or for the following subtrees is a common enough use case that I'm trying to find a more succinct way to express it using a macro. The macro I have right now is pretty simple, and it replaces the case where I want to rescale everything to come from a point in the middle of the definition of a tree.

```
\newcommand{\rescale}[1]{"{\psset{scaleby = #1}}}

\jtree
\! = {X}
    :{Y} {Z} \rescale{0.5 1}
    :{A} {B}.
\endjtree
```

[image: a jtree with narrowly spaced nodes to the right]

But given this definition, if I want to use it between subtrees, the quotation mark is set above the tree, the text of some nodes is misaligned, and no rescaling of branches occurs.

```
\jtree[scaleby = 2 1]
\! = {X}
    :{Y} {Z}.
\rescale{1 1}
\! =:{A} {B}.
\endjtree
```

[image: bad jtree]

Of course, what causes this is that in the middle of the tree, one must use `"{` prior to the `psset` macro, and `}` afterward, but this is not interpreted correctly between trees.

Given the closeness of the two macros, what I'd like is to check if the command is being issued from inside a tree definition (which I was thinking could be approximated well enough for my purposes by checking for the `.` marking the end of a tree prior to the macro). If so, it should use the version with the preceding `"`; and if not, it should not. This is admittedly a very minor and mostly aesthetic thing, since it's easy enough to type the full command, but I use the full command enough that having a single way to do it would ultimately save a lot of typing time and a few headaches. It would also simplify things when I need to go back and make adjustments to trees, since sometimes things that were in the middle of the tree before might need to get moved into a new tree, and it'd be helpful if the command to rescale the branches didn't also need to be readjusted.

Comment: I think this might be possible with Lua, if you're using LuaLaTeX.  But is it always the same environment?  It might be easier to have a boolean flag at the end of the environment that looks to see if `\blah` is the next token.

Comment: @Teepeemm - If it weren't for the OP's requirement -- that `\blah` has to be able to keep track of "what the most recent non-whitespace character before it is" -- must extend to stuff that precedes `\blah` by a line breaks, a paragraph break, and possibly even a page break, it should indeed be straightforward to set up a preprocessor-type routine that modifies the output of `\blah` suitably. For sure, the preprocessor-based approach would be much easier to implemented if one could assume that "the most recent non-whitespace character and `\blah` always occur on the same line.

Comment: @Mico In case it makes a difference, the meaning of the "most recent non-whitespace character" refers to the literal typed character in the raw TeX file, not to what the result of that is. So something like `.\newpage\blah` should produce `bar` and not `foo`.

Comment: @Jigsaw - It's the very fact that there could be a line break *in the raw TeX file* before `\blah` that makes the preprocessor-based approach unappealing.

Comment: you can not do what you ask in tex (tex has no acess to the already typeset characters) but your comment about your real context being end of environment suggests that your real use case would be solvable if you said what the issue was you want to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\psset` directly, not over another macro:

```
\jtree[scaleby = 2 1]
\! = {X}
    :{Y} {Z}.
    \psset{scaleby = 1 1}%
\! =:{A} {B}.
\endjtree
```